# How to solve the $C^\alpha$ Poisson equation on closed Riemannian manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

To be specific, suppose $M$ is a closed oriented manifold, $g$ is a Riemannian metric of $M$. 
Let $\Delta_g$ be the Laplace-Beltrami operator w.r.t. $g$.

**Prove**: Suppose $f\in C^\alpha(M)$ satisfies $\int_M f\, dVol_g=0$, then there exists a function $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(M)$ such that $\Delta_g u=f$ in $M$, and $u$ is unique up to plus a constant, here $0<\alpha<1$.

My attempt is that, firstly use $D(u):=\int_M(\frac{1}{2} |\nabla u|^2+fu)dVol_g$ is a convex functional with a lower bound on $W_0^{1,2}(M)$ to show that there exists a weak solution $u\in W^{1,2}(M)$, next use the $L^2$-regularity theory to show that $u\in W^{2,2}(M)$, but I don't know how to improve the regularity of $u$ further. (Actually, I can use the method to prove that if $f$ is $C^\infty$, then $u$ is also $C^\infty$, but I cannot extend this result to $C^\alpha$ case.)

Another attempt is Schauder estimate. However, in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book they assume that $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(M)$ already to get some interior derivative norm bound of $u$, while I don't know how to establish $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(M)$. They give a continuity method to ensure that, but it seems their discussion works for domains in Euclidean space, not for manifolds. Therefore, I want to split the question into coordinate charts, but I failed, because I don't know how to use the condition $\int_M f\, dVol_g=0$ and how to give boundary conditions in every coordinate charts.

Since I'm a novice in PDE, my presentation of the problem might have some errors. Please correct them by comments or answers. Also, any comments or answers are welcome.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've got an answer to this question.

First, use the functional $D(u)=\int_M(\frac{1}{2}|\nabla u|^2+fu)dVol_g$, we can find a weak solution $u\in W^{1,2}_0(M)$, since $f\in C^\alpha(M)$ hence in $L^2(M)$. Next we shall show that $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(M)$.

We cite theorem 6.14 from Gilbarg-Trudinger's book:

> Let $L$ be strictly elliptic in a bounded domain $\Omega$, with $c\leq0$, and let $f$ and the coefficients of $L$ belong to $C^\alpha(\overline{\Omega})$. Suppose that $\Omega$ is a $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain and that $\phi\in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline\Omega)$. Then the Dirichlet problem,
>   $$
> Lu=f \textrm{ in }\Omega,\quad u=\phi\textrm{ on }\partial\Omega,
> $$
>   has a unique solution lying in $C^{2,\alpha}(\overline\Omega)$.

The proof relies on the solvability of classical Dirichlet problem of laplacian, continuity method and Schauder estimates.

Suppose $U$ is a coordinate chart s.t. $\overline{U}$ is diffeomorphic to a closed ball, then by the theorem cited above, $\Delta_g v=f$ in $U$, $v = 0$ on $\partial U$ is solvable, and $v\in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline{U})$. Therefore, $u-v$ is a weak solution of $\Delta_g (u-v)=0$. By $L^2$-regularity, we have $u-v\in C^\infty(U)$, thus $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(U)$. Since we can choose finitely many $U$ to cover $M$, finally we have $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(M)$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

Insofar as Gilbarg and Trudinger, I think you are looking in the wrong chapter. What you should be looking for is a method to get improved *interior* regularity for *weak solutions*. That is, you should be looking at sections 8.9 and 8.11 of G&T.

Alternatively, the theorem you want is Theorem 4.7 in T. Aubin *Nonlinear analysis on Manifolds*. The method of proof is much as your first attempt: first using convexity you get a weak solution in $W^{1,2}$. Then you need to upgrade the regularity to $C^{2,\alpha}$, for which he invokes his theorem in paragraph 3.54

> Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $A$ a linear elliptic operator of order $2m$ with $C^\infty$ coefficients. If $u$ is a distributional solution to $A(u) = f$ and $f\in C^{k,\alpha}(\Omega)$, then $u\in C^{k+2m,\alpha}(\Omega)$.

For a proof Aubin refers to Theorem 6.4.3 of C.B. Morrey's *Multiple Integrals in the Calculus of Variations*. You need to (of course) use more than just $L^2$ regularity theory. (Unfortunately I do not know of a more modern exposition of this theorem, so you will have to suffer through Morrey's notation a bit.)

Comment: I've found Aubin's book, and I've seen the notation of Morrey's book through google... seems to be so complicated. Anyway, thanks for your help and reminding of G&T's right chapter~

Comment: Morrey's proof goes in two steps: first you develope/use an $L^q$ regularity theory for $1 < q < \infty$. This automatically wins you $C^{1,\alpha}$ (actually even a bit more) by Sobolev embedding from $W^{2,q}$. I'll have to parse through the chapter before I can tell you how to go from $C^{1,\alpha}$ to $C^{2,\alpha}$.

Comment: Do you think my proof listed below is correct? Or give some comments?