# When is a function laplacian of a function

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a closed (compact, boundary-less) Riemannian manifold and $f$ be a smooth function on $M$ such that $\int_M f=0,$ can we say $f=\Delta g$ for some $g$?

Comment: Yes see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172887/how-to-solve-the-c-alpha-poisson-equation-on-closed-riemannian-manifolds